# Is "up" or "upright" correct?

Tags: word-choice

The man managed to pull himself and his wheelchair back up/upright, after it flipped on its side.

(the man is in the wheelchair while he pulls himself up/upright)

1. Is "up" or "upright" correct?
2. Is the action explained in a natural way to native speakers?

Answer (score 2):

"up" refers to position, "upright" refers to orientation. Since the wheelchair was on its side, its orientation needed to be corrected, so the more precise word is "upright", but "up" isn't completely incorrect, seeing as how this does also involve raising the wheelchair upwards.